# How to animate a spinning Triangle that changes colors (randomly) as it spins

Tags: animation, graphics, wolfram-mathematica, trigonometry

So I wanted to create and animation of a equilateral triangle that was fixed to a center and that had its three vertices on a circle and as it spun is continuously changed colors in a random pattern.

So far I have:

```
Animate[Graphics[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
   Triangle[{{-1/2 - Cos[i], 0 - 1/2 Tan[i]}, {1/2 - Cos[i], 
      0 - 1/2 Tan[i]}, {0 - Cos[i], 3^(1/2)/2 - 1/2 Tan[i]}}]}], {i, 
  0, 2*Pi}]
```

Output currently (Triangle does everything except spin)
[image]

Output I'm hoping for:

[Spinning Triangle](https://j.gifs.com/oQVkx3.gif)

I was hoping to know what I have done incorrect and how would I fix my code to work correctly.

Comment: why dont you use `Rotate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how to do this using `Rotate`

```
c = RegionCentroid[SSSTriangle[1, 1, 1]];
Animate[Graphics[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
   Rotate[SSSTriangle[1, 1, 1], i, c]},
  PlotRange -> {{c[[1]] - 2/3, c[[1]] + 2/3}, {c[[2]] - 2/3, 
     c[[2]] + 2/3}}], {i, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

the problem with the original is that your formula is simply wrong. This works.

```
Animate[Graphics[{Hue[RandomReal[]],
   Triangle[{{Sin[i], Cos[i]}, {Sin[i + 2 Pi/3], 
      Cos[i + 2 Pi/3]}, {Sin[i + 4 Pi/3], Cos[i + 4 Pi/3]}}]},
  PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 3/2}, {-3/2, 3/2}}], {i, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Good solving are processing.org
You can create animation, easy to put on web.

Comment: does this answer tbe question?